# replace specific number of values after a specific occurrence in a vector

Tags: r, vector, indexing

Toy model here.  This data represents the days in the year in which an individual person gets a medical condition, for example a cold.  This vector has been produced using daily probabilities and the rbinom function.  As example, if a person gets a cold that only lasts one day, they might have two additional days of immunity following the day with the cold so my question is how to convert a vector of this form, where I add two more days of "immunity (= 1) to the original cold day.

change this:

```
0010001000001001
```

to this :

```
0011101110001111
```

I've had a look at the 'which' function and can find the index of the 1's in the original vector, but don't know how to replace the two indexes  after each '1' with a '1'.  I'm also thinking that I want the new vector to be the same length as the previous, ie no additions onto the end if values close to the end are '1'.

EDIT:
I've fashioned this looping function, which does the job but I expect there are much more elegant and efficient solutions. Also, it will fail if I get a 0,1,1 sequence in my original vector.  Any suggestions?

```
rm(list=ls())
library(zoo)
DayNonSup <- 80
VecLen <- 345
stuff1 <- rep(0,VecLen)
stuff1[c(15,35,335)] <- 1

convert <- function (vector, d) {
    for (i in 1:100) {
        a <-  which(rollapply(vector, 3, identical, c(0,1,0)))[1] + 1
        if(is.na(a)) {break}
        vector[a:(a+d)] <- 1
    }
    vector
}
stuff2 <- convert(stuff1,DayNonSup)[1:VecLen]
stuff2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a vector such as `s` below:

```
s <- unlist(strsplit('0010001000001001', ''))
s
[1] "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1"
```

You can use `dplyr` lag function as follows:

```
s[lag(s) == '1' | lag(s, n = 2) == '1'] <- '1'
s
[1] "0" "0" "1" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

You can adapt this soulution if your vector of values are numeric 0 / 1 instead. Just replace `'1'` with `1`.

EDIT: Based on the new requirement below, I suggest using something like this. You find out which original string positions have 1's. Then, get a list of 80 indices beyond that. Curtail the whole thing to make sure indexes picked stay within length of the original string. Use unique of these indices to substitute 1's. Hope this meets what you need.

```
index <- unique(unlist(lapply(which(s == '1'),
                       function(x) {
                         index <- x:(x + 80); index <- index[index < length(s)]
                         })))
s[index] <- '1'
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified my example, and can not figure out how to manipulate this to my needs.  Currently my array can be 450 values long, with only one or two 1's in it.  I need to add ~ 80 1's (days of immunity) after each 1 in the original.  Any suggestions? Tx

Answer (score 1):

We can do with `gsub` if this is a string.  We use a regex lookaround to match 1 followed by two numbers `.{2}` and replace it with two 1's

```
gsub("(?<=1).{2}", "11", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "0011101110001111"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "0010001000001001"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer working with a vector as apposed to data stored in a string.

```
str1 <- '0010001000001001'
vec <- unlist(strsplit(str1, ''))
df <- data.frame(day = vec,
                 daymin1 = c(0,vec[1:(length(vec)-1)]),
                 daymin2 = c(0,0,vec[1:(length(vec)-2)]))
apply(df,1,max)
```

This is with `base`. The `dplyr::lag` function mentioned in the other answer, is also a nice solution.